# How to show tax percentage for current product in magento?

Tags: magento2, tax

I have tried many way but i can't get the solution. How to show current product tax percentage in magento 2?

Comment: you need to post what have you tried so far so that people who see this question can help you with it.

Comment: i tried but it's only displays tax class